# A function to preload images - need to draw them now, but how?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm dabbling with canvas. And I'm a little lost on something.

I have this function:

```
function preloadimages(arr) {
        var newimages = []
        var arr = (typeof arr != "object") ? [arr] : arr
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            newimages[i] = new Image()
            newimages[i].src = arr[i]
        }
    }
```

And I call it like so:

```
preloadimages(['images/background.png', 'images/hero.png', 'images/monster.png']);
```

The only problem is, I don't know how to then draw them again later.

If I was preloading one image inside my js I would say:

```
var bgOk = false;
var bg = new Image();
bg.onload = function () {
    bgOk = true;
};
bg.src = "images/background.png";
```

and then further down when I wanted it drawn I would say:

```
if (bgOk) {
        context.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
    }
```

And that would be that. The problem is I have made a preloader class, I don't really know how now to call in just the image I want to draw now, or even how to implement the bgOk idea so that if it loaded ok, I can draw it, and if not, leave it alone.

Could someone advise me on this? I'm basically just trying to go more class based rather than the dirty great mess I normally have with a huge javascript file that is ugly and not as maintainable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a complicated problem, but in reality isn't as bad as it looks. If you want to use pre-existing code, or just want to look at something for ideas you can have a look at: http://thinkpixellab.com/pxloader/ This library was used in the HTML5 version of Cut The Rope.

A simple custom implementation could be something like the following:

```
function loadImages(arr, callback) {
    this.images = {};
    var loadedImageCount = 0;

    // Make sure arr is actually an array and any other error checking
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = imageLoaded;
        img.src = arr[i];
        this.images[arr[i] = img;
    }

    function imageLoaded(e) {
        loadedImageCount++;
        if (loadedImageCount >= arr.length) {
            callback();
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
var loader = loadImages(['path/to/img1', 'path/to/img2', 'path/to/img3'], function() {
    ctx.drawImage(loader.images['path/to/img1']); // This would draw image 1 after all the images have been loaded

    // Draw all of the loaded images
    for (var i = 0; i < loader.images.length; i++) {
        ctx.drawImage(loader.images[i]);
    }
});
```

If you want more details on asset loading you can have a look at the asset loading section of Udacity's HTML5 Game Development course https://www.udacity.com/course/cs255

Comment: I thank you for taking the time to write all that, as well as the links you've provided :) Thanks!

Comment: @DavidG No problem, I hope it helps.

Comment: Quick question if you don't mind. How would I then draw one of those images to canvas?
I have var context = canvas.createCanvas(); and context.drawImage(bg, 0, 0); previously

Comment: I made a small edit taking from what @Jarrod did. Another alternative could be to use a simple state machine to manage when things are being loaded and once everything is loaded have the system move onto the actual interaction of what you are building, but that is a conversation for another day :).

Comment: Amazing solution. There is a typo:

`this.images[arr[i]] = img;
`
(miss a ] in your code)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it's just what I needed!

Answer (score 4):

A function I use:

```
function ImageLoader(sources, callback) 
{
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;

    // get num of sources
    for (var src in sources) {
        numImages++;
    }

    for (var src in sources) {
        images[src] = new Image();
        images[src].onload = function() {

            if (++loadedImages >= numImages) {
                callback(images);
            }
        };
        images[src].src = sources[src];
    }
}
```

You call it like so:

```
var sources = {
    bg: path/to/img.png,
    title: path/to/img/png
};

var _images = {};
isReady = ImageLoader(sources, function(images) {
    _images = images;
});
```

And then to access your images

```
_images.bg;
```

**Example:** `drawImage(_images.bg, 0, 0);`